# Como colocar dados retornados de Web Service em Json (GET) para um array ou variável em c#

Tags: c#, rest, get, httpclient

Viva, estou a invocar um web service em Rest, consigo aceder á resposta mas queria organizar os dados que são retornados(que estão em Json), para um array ou variáveis mas como posso faze-lo?
Obrigado de avanço.

```
public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                string errorMessage;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("******", "************");
                client.GetType();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));              
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(EndPoint);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>();
                    var _dataResponse = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));                       
                    var daraMember = _dataResponse["member"]["href"];                     
                }

                client.Dispose();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              errorMessage= ex.Message;
          }
```

Queria retirar esta informação:

```
{"member": [{
"href": "aquamandev.adp.pt/maximo/oslc/os/zwssr/_U1IvMTAwMDYwNQ--"}], 
"href": "aquamandev.adp.pt/maximo/oslc/os/zwssr", 
"responseInfo": 
{ "totalPages": 1, 
  "href": "aquamandev.adp.pt/maximo/oslc/os/…", 
  "totalCount": 1, 
   "pagenum": 1 } 
}
```

Comment: você quer consumir os dados desse webservice?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes sim e colocar num array segue o que web service retorna em json, vou colocar na questão

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa Deserializar o **_dataResponse** para uma classe que seja compatível com este retorno.

Por exemplo:

```
public class DataResponse
{
    public IList<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [JsonPropertyName("_rowstamp")]
    public string Rowstamp { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    
    ...
}
```

**EDIÇÃO:**
Como disse a cima, você tem que trabalhar com [serialização/deserialização](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/) de dados.

> A serialização é o processo de conversão do estado de um objeto em um formulário que possa ser persistido ou transportado. O complemento de serialização é desserialização, que converte um fluxo em um objeto. Juntos, esses processos permitem que os dados sejam armazenados e transferidos.

[Esse processo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) serve para você converter esses fluxos para classes que seu sistema espera e conhece.

Segue um exemplo mostrando como faria com sua resposta. https://dotnetfiddle.net/otZscV

Comment: por favor pode ver o que coloquei na questão ? contem a resposta do web service

Comment: Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo contendo o seu caso. O que vale observar disso é que você precisa saber de antemão a resposta do Web Service, e então você prepara uma classe com a estrutura adequada para receber as informações desereliazadas.